# fetching records in the form of chain

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a SQL query to fetch records in the form of chain.

Here is an example:

If A has invited by B and after accepting invitation by A the chain
will start.

In this chain I want to show records like

- A was invited by B
- B was invited by C
- C was invited by D

Can you please help me write the query?

here is structure

Applicants table

```
id     Name   email
100   ABC  abc@test.com
101   PQR  pqr@test.com
102   XYZ  xyz@test.com
....... .......

Roommates table

id      email             created_by
1001    xyz@test.com      101
1002    pqr@test.com      100
............. .............
```

according to created_by field we should display following result

Result should be -

```
XYZ invited by PQR
PQR invited by ABC
..... ......
```

Comment: Hmmm -- can you please post your table structure?  Sample data and desired results would also be helpful...

Comment: I have updated the question please check.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need join to do this:

```
select
    A.Name || ' invited by ' || C.Name
from Roommates as R
    inner join Applicants as A on A.id = R.applicant_id
    inner join Applicants as C on C.id = R.created_by
```

**update**:

```
create or replace function get_chain(_id int)
returns table(data text)
as
$$
   with recursive cte as (
       select r.created_by, a.id as applicant_id
       from roommates as r
           inner join applicants as a on a.email = r.email
       where r.created_by = _id

       union all

       select r.created_by, a.id as applicant_id
       from roommates as r
           inner join applicants as a on a.email = r.email
           inner join cte as c on c.applicant_id = r.created_by
   )
   select
       A."Name" || ' invited by ' || R."Name"
   from cte as c
       inner join Applicants as A on A.id = c.applicant_id
       inner join Applicants as R on R.id = c.created_by
$$
language sql;
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3106e/1)

Comment: Yep, a self join seems quite sufficient. I was initially thinking the user wanted one row for the whole chain, in which case you'd probably want a recursive CTE, but it's not necessary for this.

Comment: @CraigRinger yep, title of the question made me thinking about recursion too, but I don't see it in the input/output examples

Comment: Hey Roman,
thanks.

My concern is that its right now fetcing all the records correctly but I want to fetch chain which will start from paticular record or you can consider it as a group and like wise there will be several groups.

Comment: @AjayY could you provide an example output for such a chains? Is it like you want to provide an id of applicant and find all the chains (starting from applicant_id or starting from created_by)?

Comment: I have just updated question please check, and please consider this a a single group. there will be multiple group like this.

Comment: @Roman, It is just like A is invited to B, B to C and C to you.
Then once you accept the request from C. It should give me result like-

you has invited by C,
C has invited by B,
B has invited by A

Please let me know if you understand the scenario else I will put it in another way. Please help me out.

Comment: @Roman, I verified it on my DB,but its not back tracking the requests.

Comment: @AjayY I'm sure I can help you if you will be more precise - may be you can create sql fiddle with test data and say what results you want to get? Are results look correct in my sqlfiddle?

Comment: @RomanPekar, sorry I am not able to add image system is not allowing me to do so, I am trying to rovide in the word file format but the format is getting disturbed. I am not able to send you. Let me know what I can do ?

Comment: @joop it was created on first version of OP question, after that question was updated. See edits to see initial schema

Comment: @AjayY not image. Try sqlfiddle.com - you can create table there, write desired output in comments and post link here